# Cannot create a symbolic link in a Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-11

One of my users is having some difficult when attempting to run a makefile they have inherited. When they do so, the error `ln: failed to create symbolic :'file.name': Operation not permitted`.

The project is on a folder being shared from the host Windows 11 PC, mounted onto an Ubuntu virtual machine using Oracle VM.

I have attempted to solve this using old similar issues. Firstly, I've ensured that Developer Mode is enabled on Windows. It was enabled and the user can create symbolic links both in Windows, and in the Ubuntu VM outside of the shared folders.

The other solution was to run `VBoxManage.exe setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARED_NAME 1` in the host OS. I tried this and it didn't work, and have proceeded to attempt every possible format of what it wants from the folder name. If I run getextradata, I see that all these settings are enabled. However, symbolic links are still not able to be created in the shared folder.